# Create a Debian NAS that can share between linux, windows and OSX

Tags: debian, nas, samba

Until recently I have been using samba installed on ubuntu to create a NAS that I can put up on my PC.

At Christmas I am getting a mac and I want my NAS to be able to share files to Linux, PC and OSX.

I just reinstalled my server with debian, so should I be putting on Samaba to create my NAS, or will this limit me to PC only? Im also option to other software that might do a better job.

Answer (score 0):

There are samba clients too, not just samba servers. I run a NAS with samba installed and access it from Windows and GNU/Linux computers.

As far as better software goes, I've only used Samba.